# What is the difference between Rand Index (RI) and Simple Matching Coeffiecient (SMC) in clustering?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I don't understand the difference between Rand Index (RI) and Simple matching Coefficient (SMC). From the calculation provided in the following page, the calculation looks so similar.

RI: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

SMC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_matching_coefficient

Are they kind of the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They can both be interpreted as **accuracy** of something but that is a fairly shallow level where they are "the same" because the accuracy is computed on different values.

See also ACC here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers

The differences are:

- How you compute the four values in the first place - by simple matching or by *pairs* (Rand)
- How and where you use it, e.g. in classification or distance
- The concepts and theoretical arguments for using this equation - the **why** this is the right thing to do

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse. I am matching by pair (RAND) for clustering evaluation.  Not sure yet if I understand the answer....

Comment: SMC compares two arrays, position by position (not pairs of clusters) on whether they match. So "woof" and "wool" match in 3 of 4 positions.